# SQL select & Group if at least one exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select & Group `Id` & `Pid` when  at least 1 for each `Pid` in `Id` has `IsExists=1`

```
Id     Pid     Opt   IsExists
27      2      107    1
27      2      108    0
27      5      96     1
51      9      17     1
51      9      18     0
51      10     112    0
758     25     96     0
758     97     954    1
758     194    2902   1
758     194    2903   1
```

The result should be:

```
Id  IsExists
27     1
```

- In the result for `[id=27 | pid=2]` & for `[id=27 | pid=5]`  has at least 1 with `isExists=1`

Is it possible?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Can a ID have only one PID associated to it ? So For ID= 27 PID=2 and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select id
from (select id, pid, max(isexists) as max_isexists
      from t
      group by id, pid
     ) t
having count(*) = sum(max_isexists);
```

This assumes that `isexists` takes on the values 0 and 1.

An alternative only uses one level of aggregation but is a bit trickier, using `count(distinct)`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(distinct pid) = count(distinct case when isexists = 1 then pid end);
```

Comment: Don't you need `distinct` in the second `count`? Or is there only one per grouping anyway?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . Yes.

Comment: I think your query has one problem (I used the second one). when Pid = 0 and it's only listed once. I edit my question: For Id=758, Pid= 25 IsExists=0 but this Id is listed in the result of the query. by the way, thank you very much!

Comment: @Eyal . . . The `count(distinct)` on both sides fixes that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested aggregation:

```
select Id
from
 (
   select Id, Pid, 
      -- returns 1 when value exists
      max(IsExists) as maxExists
   from tab
   group by Id, Pid
 ) as dt
group by Id
     -- check if all Pid got a 1
having min(maxExists) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... it uses the inner group by to get the distinct counts of IsExists by ID and PID and the outer one checks if there are 2 or more

```
SELECT ID, 1 as IsExists FROM
(
    select ID, PID ,  Count(Distinct IsExists) as IsExists 
    FROM
    (

        Select 27 as ID , 2 as PID , 1 as IsExists UNION ALL
        Select 27 as ID , 2 as PID , 0 as IsExists UNION ALL
        Select 27 as ID , 5 as PID , 1 as IsExists UNION ALL
        Select 51 as ID , 9 as PID , 1 as IsExists UNION ALL
        Select 51 as ID , 9 as PID , 0 as IsExists UNION ALL
        Select 51 as ID , 10 as PID , 0 as IsExists

    ) a
    WHERE IsExists = 1
    Group by ID, PID
) B
GROUP BY B.ID 
Having  Count(*) >= 2
```